# cron run script B after the successful execution of script A

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

Two bash scripts,  A and script B
how to schedule cron to run script B after successful execution of script A.

```
***** /home/scripts/A.sh ; /home/scripts/B.sh
```

Above one will run simultaneously  but i should run B.sh after script A finish execution successfully

Comment: "_will run simultaneously_"? Are you sure? As far as I know this is a shell sequential list and they will run one after the other. What makes you think they will run in parallel? And if you want to run the second only if the first succeeded use `&&` as a separator instead of `;`.

Comment: Thanks I will use this &&

Comment: Alternatively, if script modification is ok, you only need `A.sh` in cronjob, at the end of the script `A.sh`, you call `B.sh`.  When you have finished the job at `A.sh`, it will call `B.sh`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
command1 && command2
```

command2 would only be run, if command1 returns an exit status of zero.